# What is best practice to data-based authorization in micro-service architecture

Tags: c#, jwt, authorization, asp.net-identity, microservices

Assume that we hava couplse of micro services (order, delivery , shipping , ... ) in the back-end also there is a identity server which authenticates client and issues JWT tokens, so all of the services don't care about security issues.

identity server tells which user has which roles such as "Admin" , "Customer" , "Delivery Agent" , ...

I want to limit users CUD actions in all of the services in single point (i think identity server is best choice for that). the limitations are set of some cities and some streets

for example "Ali" has access to

```
[ {"city-1":{"st-10","st-12" ... < n > ... "st-x"}} 
,{"city-5":{"st-10","st-12" ... < n > ... "st-x"}} 
..
..]
```

Assuming this when Ali requests all the orders that placed in "city-10" from `OrderService` it should be say `403 Status Code` or empty result. or when Ali requests `getAllOrders()` from `OrderService` the result should contains just orders that has been placed in `[ {"city-1":{"st-10","st-12" ... < n > ... "st-x"}}  ,{"city-5":{"st-10","st-12" ... < n > ... "st-x"}}  .. ..]` .

whats is the best practice to tackling with that?
Does it make sense to put these kind of authorization data inside jwt token ? or keep jwt simple and let the services to call an api exposed by identity service by given token and get the user accesses?

OR

maybe you say this is not identity service duties at all!

so please advice me and let me know this your experiences.

thanks

Comment: *this is not identity service duties at all* I would say that. The identity model stored in JWT is nothing compared to how complicated your business rules can be. You could have another microservice for that and use it in other services.

Comment: So if i have another service to authorize the user, then how it acts? consider we have simple jwt token produced by identity server and it contains just userid. OrderService receives a request and now it needs to know what are user access domains (which cities and which streets), so at the beginning process calls an api from authorize-service to retrieve user permission details. but in this way we have performance issue because have permission request per business requests. whats your opinion about this?
@WiktorZychla

Comment: If performance is your concern, include authorization domain in each service directly, without making a separate service for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could look up OAuth. The identity service can authenticate the client and put authorization scope in the JWT token, and the services can authorize the requests based on the scope.

Comment: dear Salil. thank you about your solution, look, As i say in the question, the access domain's format is a long json array containing cities and its streets, (about average 4k characters) in this way scopes may be longer than usual and it increases the JWT token size then its not seems to be good idea because that imposes a considerable overhead.